# Create, open and edit excel sheet in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am new to flutter. I am asked to develop a website using flutter which picks excel file from device and edits it.
I am trying to do it by using `excel: ^1.1.5` package.
I am able to pick excel file, read its data and create a new excel sheet. The problem is I am unable to open selected file in `chrome`. I have tried `open_file` package but it is only for `android` and `ios` devices.

Comment: Have you tried the [Excel package](https://pub.dev/packages/excel)?

Comment: Yes. It only creates excel file. I want to open newly created file. Kindly help.